# Microsoft365 - Teams calendar/Guest access

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I have been recently added to the teams with my external gmail.com mail address. I'm not appearing in this teams as I guest, but as a normal person (member). I can also see calendar.

I tried to reproduce such a situation with my Microsoft 365 Developer enviroment, but I just cannot work it out. When I add user to Teams he always has a Guest role. See below image for the reference. HOME is a group that I was added to, Elitezone is a Teams enviroment that I created, and added my mail as a guest.

[Image that shows how it looks like on teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIgEa.png)

Also on my teams I cannot see Calendar...or create I meeting, and on the Teams that I was added it is easly possible.

Do you know how can I work it out? I tried adding people directly from Azure AD/Microsoft 365 Admin Center or Teams, but it never works.

On teams HOME everyone is Member, and no one is Guest even tho we all use private emails from different sources.

Comment: Do you have E1-O365 developer license assigned to you?

Comment: I have assigned to every user Microsoft 365 E5 Developer

Comment: Than you will have access to those

Comment: But calendar is not visible when I log to theirs accounts. They are also not visible in Teams admin panel.

Comment: Do they have access to office365 group calendar? if not you need to provide access to those Guest or sharing the outlook calendar